# Cleaning the duplicates with a reference from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reference, duplicates

I want to get rid of the duplicates by using correct information in the another data frame.

The problem is original data has the duplicates both with the right values and wrong values. The right values are defined in another data frame, so I want to use that data frame as a reference for those rows.

So the job I want to do conditional for two rows. To illustrate it, lets say the original data is `tree1` :

```
tree1 = data.frame( 
sp = c("oak","pine","apple","birch","oak","pine","apple","maple"), 
code = c(23:26,77,88,99,27))
> tree1
     sp code
1   oak   23
2  pine   24
3 apple   25
4 birch   26
5   oak   77
6  pine   88
7 apple   99
8 maple   27
```

And the reference data is `tree2`:

```
tree2 = data.frame( sp = c("oak","pine","apple"),
                    code = 23:25)
> tree2
     sp code
1   oak   23
2  pine   24
3 apple   25
```

And my desired output that I get rid of the duplicates with wrong values where I still have the original data should seem like below:

```
> tree3
     sp code
1   oak   23
2  pine   24
3 apple   25
4 birch   26
5 maple   27
```

I know that it seems like an easy conditional operation but I ended up deleting some original values or keeping the duplicates with wrong values in the end (other way around is not working). Simple R-base help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of the duplicates altogether, since the corresponding correct values are in second data frame anyway, and row-bind those

```r
rbind(
  tree1[!(duplicated(tree1$sp) | duplicated(tree1$sp, fromLast = TRUE)), ],
  tree2
)
#>      sp code
#> 4 birch   26
#> 8 maple   27
#> 1   oak   23
#> 2  pine   24
#> 3 apple   25
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found the solution easy to understand (convenient for other datasets) and it worked quite fast in the real data. Plus, I have done some controls on the output and what is produced as an output seems correct.

Answer (score 3):

One option using base R `mapply`. Assuming you have same columns in `tree1` and `tree2` and in same order we can check values in `tree1` which are present in `tree2` and select only those rows where all the values match or no values match.

```
vals <- rowSums(mapply(`%in%`, tree1, tree2))
tree1[vals == ncol(tree1) | vals == 0, ]

#    sp  code
#1   oak   23
#2  pine   24
#3 apple   25
#4 birch   26
#8 maple   27
```

Comment: Thanks, however it is a value based solution and I have tried another version of it before. It may seem like it is working in a hypothetical data but I've got 139 rows instead of 2749 rows for the real data. So I was looking for something comparison of the info in the rows rather than sum of the values.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)
tree2bis <- filter(tree1, !(tree1$sp %in% tree2$sp)) # dataframe with no duplicated rows
tree1 %>% inner_join(tree2) %>% bind_rows(tree2bis)
# output
     sp code
1   oak   23
2  pine   24
3 apple   25
4 birch   26
5 maple   27
```

Comment: Thanks. dplyr is a very skeptic package when it comes to deal with massive dataset especially on merging datasets. I have got so many warnings in the end and it is impossible to check where it goes wrong in a big dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Also a `dplyr` possibility:

```
tree1 %>%
 filter(code %in% tree2$code | !sp %in% tree2$sp)

     sp code
1   oak   23
2  pine   24
3 apple   25
4 birch   26
5 maple   27
```

Or:

```
tree1 %>%
 left_join(tree2, by = c("sp" = "sp")) %>%
 filter(code.x == code.y | (!is.na(code.x) & is.na(code.y))) %>%
 transmute(sp = sp,
           code = code.x)

     sp code
1   oak   23
2  pine   24
3 apple   25
4 birch   26
5 maple   27
```

Or the first possibility in `base R`:

```
subset(tree1, code %in% tree2$code | !sp %in% tree2$sp)
```

Comment: R-base solution is fantastic, wonder why I couldn't come up with this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this using `data.table` package-

```
> setDT(tree2)[setDT(tree1),on=.(sp)][!(duplicated(sp)),.(sp,i.code)]

     sp    i.code
1:   oak     23
2:  pine     24
3: apple     25
4: birch     26
5: maple     27
```